# How to controll time indepedently from time on users phone in my firebase app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app where users can predict the outcome of a soccer match. The problem is that if the user changes the time on their phone they can still predict even after it has ended. How do I prevent this so that it's independent of the time on each user's phone?
Thank you

Comment: Add the structure of your firestore so I could guild you on how to write database rule. To denied any prediction after the expiration time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to not get the date from the local device, but get it from the firebase `timestamp` that it offers, as example if we say that you want to do it from now until tomorrow at the same time, you can save it to your DB, using:

```
Timestamp(Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch , 24*60*60*1000)
```

in your case, you need to compare the `Timestamp` we set in the database with:

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

also, you can get a DateTime from a `Timestamp` with this:

```
 final firestoreTimestamp = /* the Timestamp object */;
 firestoreTimestamp.toDate();
```

Comment: And hacker will still be able to change call, and will use his own timestamp. This is a way you should write requests, but not a way to prevent hackers from changing requests.

Comment: the timestamp is a Firebase-specific class, read https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: the values you get and save to firebase of timestamp are linked to firebase, not the client device

Comment: Dude hacker can change that Firebase timestamp to his own modified Firebase timestamp. You should read documentation, which says you should always make rules in your database if you want to secure it!!!

Comment: Did you mention something about security or firebase rules in your question,  you asked a question and I give the answer based on the question read. how the hacker will change the Timestamp of a mobile app while on release, flutter obfuscates the dart code, the thing about accesing security rules can be modified directly and easily only from the web version

Comment: I didn't ask a question. And your database is not secure.

Comment: my mistake thinking that you're the one who asked

Answer (score 1):

The safest and most recommended approach for this is to use database rules.
Patiently study this https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes